# Set theory operation and topology

Tags: general-topology

As I was looking at Munkres' Topology, I was trying this exercise, as in the picture (to show if each statement is true). What is a good way to understand and memorize them, if there's any good method? Thanks! [image]

Comment: Don't memorize. Use Venn diagrams.

Comment: Don't memorize. Understand the definitions of the basic operations on sets and inclusion. If need be, re-derive some of the proofs.

Answer (score 1):

The proofs are all standard ,and can be quickly redone in your head if needed.
You can get a sense of their truth by drawing some Venn diagrams.

Some pointers:

$p \implies q$ is shown by assuming $p$ to be true and then proving $q$, using that.

$A \subset B$ is shown by: pick an arbitary element $a$ from $A$ and show it must lie in $B$.

$A = B$ is shown by doing both $A \subset B$ and $B \subset A$.

Don't memorise them, that's not the point. Learn to reason correctly about sets, know the relevant definitions (like intersection, union, product, difference), and you can deduce all the relevant facts yourself.